# How do I create a Unary association in CakePhp?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a shortcut for creating Unary associations in Cake?

For example, a user is a friend of another user. I'm pretty sure it's going to violate cake's conventions if I try it the hard way and code the associations myself.

Cake has HABTM:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'friends',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id',
            'unique' => true
        )
);
```

Will this work? A user model assoc to another user model.

**Update:**
How do I save the data now?

```
$this->data["Friend"] = $request["Requester"];
$this->data["Admirer"] = $request["Requestee"];                         
$this->Friend->create();
$this->Friend->save($this->data);
```

$request["Requester"] and $request["Requestee"] both hold objects of type User. 
The HABTM rel is defined in the User model

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friend' => array(
            'className' => 'Friend',
            'joinTable' => 'friends',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'id'
        ),
        'Admirer'=>array(
            'className'=>'Friend',
            'joinTable'=>'friends',
            'foreignKey' => 'friend_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'id',            
        )
    );
```

All that happens is the $data->["Friend"]'s id is stored in the id column of the friends table

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution I use in an example application

Two tables are needed, users and followers. The important fields are User->id, Follower->user_id, Follower->friend_id.

I hope this snippet helps.

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $useTable='users';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany=array(
        'Friend'=>array(
            'className'=>'User',
            'joinTable'=>'followers',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id',
            ),
        'Admirer'=>array(
            'className'=>'User',
            'joinTable'=>'followers',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            ),
        );
}
```

-teh

Comment: To match the singular model name format, I would recommend using 'Friend' instead of 'Friends', and 'Admirer' instead of 'Admirers'.  Other than that, this is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Bjorn,

he is asking about User habtm User...

your join table should be users_users and the relation should look like this

```
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friend' =>
                array(
                        'className' => 'UserUser',
                        'joinTable' => 'users_users',
                        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                        'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id',
                        'unique' => true
                )
);
```

i think that should do the trick

Comment: and 'Friend' has a separate model and controller than User?

Comment: The join table doesn't *have* to be called users_users, but if you want to use Cake's automagic, then it should be.

Comment: Also, the className value should just be "User" if that's the name of your Model.  You can define a join table if you like via: 'with' => 'UsersUser', but that's only necessary if there's additional HABTM data on the join table.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP there are several variables in your model available to do that, like $hasMany, $belongsTo and $hasAndBelongsToMany. Please read the Cookbook for further explaination.. http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together .

In your example, I think you need HABTM.

Comment: It's not really helpful just sending him to read all the models. He obviously already did.