# Not getting all the data I need for an association in CakePHP app

Tags: php, cakephp

I have built an app in CakePHP where Users can be friends with other Users. A user has a profile and the friendships are linked between then user ids in a friends table (models further down)

In my FriendsController I pass a username and then use the following method to get Friends for a User: **Note this method is in my User Model and called like: `$this->User->getFriends($username);` in my FriendsController!**

```
function getFriends($username) {
        //Start by getting User's ID
        $user = $this->find(
            'first',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.username' => $username
                )
            )
        );


        $profileAndFriends = $this->Profile->find(
            'first',  //Because User hasOne Profile, so we'll fetch this one profile.
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Profile.user_id' => $user['User']['id']
                ),
                'contain' => array(
                    'UserFrom' => array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'status' => 1
                        )
                    ),
                    'UserTo' => array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'status' => 1
                        )
                    )
                )             
            )
        );
        return $profileAndFriends;
    }
```

My User Model:

class User extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'User';

```
public $hasOne = 'Profile';

public $hasMany = array(
    'UserFrom'=>array(
        'className'=>'Friend',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
    ),
    'UserTo'=>array(
        'className'=>'Friend',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
    )
);
```

}

and my Profile model:

```
class Profile extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Profile';

    public $belongsTo = 'User';
}
```

and the Friend model:

```
class Friend extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Friend';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'UserFrom'=>array(
            'className'=>'User',
            'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
        ),
        'UserTo'=>array(
            'className'=>'User',
            'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
        )
    );
}
```

So in my view I have:

```
<?php foreach ($friends as $friend) : ?>

        <?php echo $friend['UserTo']['firstname']; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

However it can't understand the firstname part! So...

If I do a debug on $friend in the view I get:

```
array(
    'Friend' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_from' => '6',
        'user_to' => '8',
        'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'status' => '1'
    ),
    'UserFrom' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '6',
        'username' => 'driz',
        'email' => 'cameron@driz.co.uk',
        'status' => '1',
        'code' => '6d446abefc2f1214e561da6f93470621',
        'lastlogin' => '2012-04-23 15:22:04',
        'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ),
    'UserTo' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '8',
        'username' => 'testperson',
        'email' => 'test@testperson.com',
        'status' => '1',
        'code' => '7a794859b3a16dfc005dd7f80b9ac030',
        'lastlogin' => '2012-03-18 09:28:24',
        'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    )
)
```

So it's clearly an issue of the Linked Users I need to also contain there profiles... But how do I do that as If I put a contain inside the UserTo and UserFrom it throws an error saying they're not associated...

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

    public $hasOne = 'Profile';
    public $belongsTo = array(
      'Friend'=>array(
        'foreignKey' => 'user_to'
      )
    );
}

class Profile extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Profile';
    public $belongsTo = 'User';
}

class Friend extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Friend';
    public $hasOne = 'User';
}
```

Now its possible to take user friends by:

```
$this->Friend->find("all", array(
  'conditions'=>array(
    'Friend.user_from'=>$user_id,
  )
  'contain'=>array(
    'User'=>array(
      'contain'=>'Profile'
    )
  )
));
```

Comment: Don't fully understand. Could you post what I should have in each of those models... Thanks.

Comment: Hey, ok, i changed my article for a little, please read more about HABTM realization, and i written some example from your code. hope it will help.

Comment: +1 you should be using HABTM with the 'with' key if you want a custom Friend model (i.e., for the `status` field).

Comment: so how do i get the friends? or just the requests as it seems like you've combined the relationships and queries together...

Comment: Tried doing this but it doesn't work at all just throws lots of sql errors saying things are not associated etc. My code was closer just wasn't pulling the friends profiles through!

Comment: Hey.. it will never work if you just copy and paste the code, but the logic is HABTM. if something is wrong, need just to fix it a little. About your code, you will need to rewrite it anyway if there will be a little more users, because its generating really big count of queries to database.

Comment: What do I put in my Friends controller exactly to get a list of friends profiles that have their users linked to the currently viewed user as I don't get that part at all!!! I have done the associations like you have done, but I don't follow you in the controller??

Comment: Hi there, yah, thats bad. There are some theories to try, but how about making that friend taking easyer? Just take all rows from Friend model, with user you need, and join all the data you need to them. I fixed my answer a little to help you with it. Please report your results.

Comment: Plus, i found similar friend question, with HABTM realization, please read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576495/how-do-i-create-a-unary-association-in-cakephp